# Stop return back to first function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'd like to stop returning to the first function. Look at my example for better understanding:

```
function function1() {
    function2();
    console.log('back after called function'); // shoudn't log if condition is true
}

function function2() {
    if (condition === true) { // if condition is true, stop right here (no callback to function1)
        return false;
    } else {
        // callback is allowed
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can't stop it returning. Functions always return. What you can do is make the function2 return a value which tells function1 what to do next. So if a particular value is returned, then you can use an if statement in function1 to stop it running the log command.

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary operator.

```
function2() ? false : console.log('back after called function');
```

You can add more lines in as well - use an IIFE.

```
function2() ? false : (() => {
    console.log('back after called function');
    //More code
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately, I didn't get it. It still logs **back after called function**.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Just throw and caught the error

```js
function function1() {
  try{
      function2();
      console.log('back after called function'); // shoudn't log if condition is true
  }catch(e){
   console.log(e.message);
  }
      
  }


function function2() {
    if (1 === 1) { // if condition is true, stop right here (no callback to function1)
        throw new Error('forced stopped');
    } else {
        // callback is allowed
    } 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onLoad="function1()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way should be something like:

```
function function1() {
    if (function2()) {
        console.log('back after called function');
    }
}
```

As Jack Bashford suggested (but wrote in the wrong way), you could use the ternary operator:

```
function function1() {
    function2()? console.log('back after called function') : return;
}
```

Or, for a more complex code process, you could use a callback function:

```
function function1() {
    function2(function(error) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log('back after called function');
        }
    });
}

function function2(callback) {
    if (condition === true) {
        callback("Error: condition false");
    } else {
        callback(null);
    } 
}
```

EDIT:

Using my last option you can do exactly what you asked: do not return to function1:

```
function function1() {
    function2(function() {
        console.log('back after called function');
    });
}

function function2(callback) {
    if (condition === true) {
        return;
    } else {
        callback();
    } 
}
```

But I think for the sake of good practice you should always call the callback.

Comment: Just on a technical point, even the last example does still return. It's not true to say it won't return. You can't stop a function from returning. It doesn't return a value, and you didn't write an explicit return statement, but ultimately, control still returns to function1 once function2 (and the callback) have finished executing. The difference is in what function1 decides to do at that time.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible for function2 not to return to function1

`function function1() {
    if (function2()) return;
    console.log('back after called function'); // shoudn't log if condition is true
}`